# Is eating meat compatible with the training rule to abstain from killing?

Tags: personal-practice, ethics, vegetarianism

The first lay precept says “I undertake the training rule to abstain from killing.” (The formulation is from Wikipedia.) As I understand it, this rule pertains to all kinds of sentient beings.

Is eating meat compatible with this precept? Is it possible to say I am following this precept when the rule I’m following in fact is “I undertake the training rule to abstain from killing but I get someone else to do the killing for me”?

Comment: I think this question has been asked (and answered) already.

Comment: If you are looking for resources that make the case for vegetarianism, go here: http://www.shabkar.org/references/index.htm If you want to find people making the case *against* Buddhist vegetarianism, at the moment, it's the top 100 google hits. For the most part, this is a sectarian issue, i.e. you can get the answer you want by picking your sect.